# SQL combination of two tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Im pretty new to sql and php. I basically have 2 tables, 1 with images of men from a specific group, the other one with images of women from the same group. I want to create a table with all the possible couples that could be made from this database of men and women, so that the people from this group can vote on the couple that is most likely to form.

One table is called "imagesmen" with 2 columns, image_id(autoincrement), filename; and the other one called "imageswomen" with 2 columns image_id(autoincrement), and filename.

I want to combine them into the table "couples" with 4 columns: "couple_id(autoinc), image_men_id, image_women_id, votes".

The final purpose is a website where 2 people male and female are selected randomly and people can vote "likely to happen" or "not likely to happen", increasing the column "votes" by 1 or decreasing by 1.

What is the correct sql syntax to put in my php file?

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Please show your research and current approach(es)

Comment: Could you look up an SQL join statement and see if that would suit your purposes? What have you tried? Are you getting an error with something you have?

Comment: at the moment i have something like:

Comment: $imageboy="SELECT * FROM imagesboysm ORDER BY image_id ASC LIMIT 0,1";
$imagegirl="SELECT * FROM imagesgirlsm ORDER BY image_id";

Comment: I have added the *mySQL* tag to your question based on the code in your comment.

Comment: i thought the best way would be to choose the first men from the men table and assign all the women of the group (for example man 1- woman 1; man 1- woman 2 etc.) but i can't find a way to iterate it

Comment: @user3683347 The way that I suggested in my answer will give you a random selection each time - and you can easily store/update votes based on the combination you get.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using mySQL, you can easily use an `order by rand limit 1` to get a single random row of data. From there, you can then force a cartesian join to the other table and effectively get a random row from each table:

```
select
    a.id,
    a.image,
    b.id,
    b.image
from
    (
        select
            id,
            image
        from
            maleTable
        order by
            rand()
        limit 1
    ) a
        join
        (
            select
                id,
                image
            from
                femaleTable
            order by
                rand()
            limit 1
        ) b
        on 1=1
```

When you have this info, you can store the data in another table to correlate the votes that folks give with a structure like this:

```
tableVotes:
fID MID Votes
2   45  14
36  2   56
...
```

Comment: @Daan Yes, I agree that I should probably read the last paragraph of a question before posting an answer :) I have made an edit and added more information.

Comment: with the rand() limit 1 won't i get duplicated records?

Comment: @user3683347 In the initial select statement, you will get a random match of a man and a woman. When you go to update the votes, that is where you can eliminate the duplicates (by using something like `on duplicate update...` syntax.

Comment: @Fluffeh What is the code i should use for when inserting a new record in the table "Votes", to check that the records doesn't already exist? So that if the records exists, instead of inserting a new one it justs update the field "Votes" with +1?

Comment: Tip: You can use `CROSS JOIN` instead of just `JOIN` to get a join that doesn't require an `ON` clause.